# Options for using Sphinx 2.0 (or 1.1) with DataMapper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, datamapper

Unfortunately ThinkingSphinx is not an option for DataMapper (though they say support is planned).  We're using Realtime Indexes, so we need at least Sphinx version 1.1 (we're actually running version 2.0, but 1.1 should still work fine).  I've seen dm-sphinx-adapter, but that looks unmaintained and very much like a hack (you pull out the IDs manually, then search as normal... which makes me wonder what the adapter is even offering).

Anything else I may not have seen? :)

EDIT | Hmm, actually, [somebody's fork of dm-sphinx-adapter](https://github.com/david/dm-sphinx-adapter) has a nicer README that gives some options.  Using the `is :searchable` plugin makes things a bit nicer.  But I'm still keen to see more options with a sexy API that's nicely abstracted to fit more with standard DataMapper conventions.

EDIT 2 | dm-sphinx-adapter is a dead project.  Since Riddle (the pure-ruby client that ThinkingSphinx uses) is open source, I think I'll set about writing my own.  Doesn't look like there's anything out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up (many months later) creating oedipus and oedipus-dm:

https://github.com/d11wtq/oedipus-dm

We are using this successfully with our RT indexes.  We still have a lot to do, however.

Answer (score 1):

I pushed a (very old) [dm branch](https://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx/tree/dm) for Thinking Sphinx to the git repo the other week - the branch itself is about 18 months old. DataMapper doesn't have as solid support for joining to the same table multiple times as ActiveRecord does, so it was really hard to have the same featureset and reliability - which is why the branch hasn't been touched since.

If you want to have a go at resurrecting it, be my guest - and given you're in Melbourne (as am I, usually), happy even to sit down and talk through code.

Even from a Riddle perspective, the same offer applies.

As it currently stands, Riddle's 2.0.x feature support isn't quite perfect, but I'm about to spend 20+ hours on flights from later tonight, and RT Index support (via SphinxQL) is on my list of plane hacking projects. We shall see how I go, though.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I'll take a look at it when I get home and put the kettle on ;)  It would be good to be able to avoid re-inventing the wheel if there's a good basis to start from. Haha, being able to code on long distance flights definitely makes the time pass quicker.  Until you realise you need internet access for something :P

Comment: Yeah, am really hoping I don't need anything while I'm on the plane. Shame most airlines haven't got wifi (Virgin America being the notable exception).